# I want to process after "getDocuments" processing is completed in FireStore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore has a collection of "users" and "posts".
Each user's document has a collection of "posts".
"Posts" has a reference type "post" and the value is "posts / documentID".

I want to get the user's post list, I tried to realize with the following code, but "print (self.postsData)" is empty.

How can I do that?

```
class postFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var postsData: [PostModel] = []
    private let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    private let uid: String
    private var db: Firestore!
    private let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    private let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue")

    init() {
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        uid = self.userDefaults.object(forKey: "userDataUid") as! String
        fetchPostsData()
    }

    func fetchPostsData() {
        self.db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("posts").getDocuments { (snaps, err) in

            guard let snaps = snaps else { return }

            for document in snaps.documents {
                self.dispatchGroup.enter()
                self.dispatchQueue.async(group: self.dispatchGroup) { [weak self] in
                    self?.asyncProcess(document: document) { () -> Void in
                        self?.dispatchGroup.leave()
                    }
                }
            }

            self.dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                print(self.postsData)
            }
        }
    }

    func asyncProcess(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot, completion: () -> Void) {
        let refarence: DocumentReference = document.data()["post"] as! DocumentReference

        refarence.getDocument { (snap, err) in

            guard let snap = snap else { return }
            self.postsData.append(PostModel(
                documentId: snap.documentID,
                text: snap.data()!["text"] as! String
            ))
        }
        completion()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `completion()` in the wrong place. It needs to be inside the curly brace that currently precedes it.

Also, you are referring to `self.postsData` from different threads. Bad idea. Wrap all calls to read or write  shared data in some common dispatch queue. Even better, do not share data at all! Hand the results back thru the completion handler.

Comment: Also `guard let snap = snap else { return }` is wrong. Every path out must call the completion handler.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Writing "completion ()" in parentheses of "refarence.getDocument" resulted in the error "Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion'".

Comment: Yes, you have to specify that it is `@escaping`.